# what's the meaning of "stations in life"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

What is the meaning of '*stations in life*'?

Does it mean religion?

'*stations in life*' as in:

Nonetheless, seams can make borders “semi- permeable membranes,” relatively more or less porous to people, depending upon their nationalities and **stations in life**, to economic 
exchange, to the passage of ideas …

Comment: Station in life - a person's social or official position in relation to others - student, doctor, lawyer, beggar

Comment: http://onelook.com/?w=station&ls=a

Comment: @mplungjan Can you get a few more references for definition/ explanation of the phrase? Thanks.

Comment: Google "define stations"

Answer (score 2):

Your station in life is your social standing. Like what level in the strata of society you exist in. It has nothing necessarily to do with religion, though that could be a factor. It has to do more with money, class, education, upbringing. Basically all of the superficial aspects that in times past when "knowing your station" in life was a really important thing. I would read the book Pride and Prejudice for a clearer understanding. I hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage.SE. Could you please provide accompanying sources and/or citation to support your answer?

Answer (score 1):

That expression is considered 'dated' today, though a convenient catch phrase in flowery speech and writing.

***[different stations in life](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/station)***

> **4.1** [count noun] • dated One’s social rank or position

[… we are defined by our jobs …](http://perpendicularities.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/stations-in-life/)

In a broader sense, perhaps, *status*, *standing*, *locus standi*, *position*.

[What determines "station in life"?](http://forums.catholic.com/showthread.php?t=633684)

> Your 'station in life' includes such things as age bracket, marital status, whether or not you have children, whether you are a priest, religious or layperson, perhaps your work status (ie if you are an employer or not).

Usage:
[Acquisition and Use of Data](http://www20.csueastbay.edu/jerhre/aim-and-scope/acquisition.html)

> … persons in various cultures, contexts and **stations in life** define and orchestrate their privacy, and best ways to understand and respect the privacy …